# Keep id on css link in production of ViteJs project

Tags: css, build, vite

In a Vanilla Typescript Vite project, I need to make a Single page application. I need to use Two css File. So in the html entry page, i use 2 link stylesheet file. I need in the application to disable one and active another.

I saw that I could use the property

```
disabled
```

of HTMLLinkElement.

So i put an id to the links on the html page, like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/login.css" id="css_login">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/lobby.css" id="css_lobby">
```

But in production, ViteJs transform it without the id :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/lobby.d0dbc25d.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/login.32f19747.css">
```

I can't select the link in JS for disable or active a specific file.

Can anyone help me ? I spent last night trying to fix the problem but couldn't find anything. Link tag attributes disappear no matter what I do.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The disabled property works well but it becomes hacky soon by modifying index.html after build and the flash of combined styles on initial load.

So I found a working alternative with Vite + React. I used shadow DOM to render multiple roots and loaded the stylesheets through link elements in the jsx itself. This way was much simpler to work with as the shadow DOM scoped the conflicting stylesheets passively. I suppose this is doable with vanilla TS.

Rendering react root inside shadow DOM example:

```
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

// create root container where react element will be inserted
let container = document.createElement("div");
container.classList.add("react-container");

// attach shadow DOM to container
const shadowRoot = container.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });

// create react element
const reactButton = <button>Submit</button>;

// get hold of an existing element in HTML DOM
const domElement = document.getElementById("name");

// insert root container element in HTML DOM after the existing element
domElement.after(container);

// shadow DOM as react root
const root = createRoot(shadowRoot);

// render react element inside shadow DOM
root.render(reactButton);
```

Using link elements to inject styles in shadow DOM (Vanilla JS) example:

```
...
this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/button.css" />
  <style>
    /* your component specific styles go here */
  </style>
  ...
`;
...
```

More info on rendering react roots inside shadow DOM: https://gourav.io/blog/render-react

More info on styles in shadow DOM: https://lamplightdev.com/blog/2021/03/23/how-to-share-styles-in-the-shadow-dom/